# Sony MSV files on Linux

Tags: linux, files, music-player

I have just bought an old Voice recorder second hand ( Sony ICD-SX68).
When I connect it to ubuntu it shows up as a usbdrive with my recorded files. 
The problem is the file format of the recording. It is msv which is sony specific.
So is there a way to convert or listen to it on Linux? 
I have looked at wine but the search that the software Sony provides can't be wined. 
What to do?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/197750/how-can-i-play-msv-audio-file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to virtualize Windows, and in Windows, run [Digital Voice Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/covnert-msv-into-mp3/files/Updated%20Sony%20ICS%20converter/) (Open Source), [Brorsoft Converter](http://www.brorsoft.cn/blu-ray-video-converter-ultimate/), [Wondershare Uniconverter](https://videoconverter.wondershare.com/), or that [Sony app](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/downloads/W0001286) you found.